# progressViewOffset is not working for IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am implementing pull to refresh in `FlatList` using `RefreshControl`. I am also providing the small snippet for the same.

```
<FlatList
        windowSize={3}
        data={this.list}
        renderItem={({ item }) => item.render}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            progressViewOffset={10}
            refreshing={trend.isFetching}
            onRefresh={this.onPullToRefresh}
            title="Pull to refresh"
          />
        }
/>
```

The issue is that I want to provide an offset so that I can dynamically set the pull down length after which my refresh function is called. I suppose `progressViewOffset` is the prop for that. But on changing its value there is no change. I want my pull down to be more sensitive like in instagram app, even on a small pull down, feeds get refresh.
p.s. This issue is for IOS.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is an android only property (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Components/RefreshControl/RefreshControl.js#L128). Therefore it is not supported on ios devices.